# tag synonyms for Apple-Silicon and M1

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I have just seen that [apple-silicon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) and [m1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m1) are separate tags. I think they should be synonyms.

I think [apple-silicon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) should be the base tag as it defines the architecture. [m1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m1) does not make sense as eventually there will be an M2 etc and most questions will be generic to Apple Silicon.

However when I suggested the synonym the web page rejected it as [m1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m1) has been used more that [apple-silicon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-silicon).

Can moderators override this?

I note [M1 tag versus Apple Silicon tag](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/m1-tag-versus-apple-silicon-tag) but noone has done anything on this and I can't give it a bounty to get it looked at again. The answer is similar to my suggestion but make the basic tag arm64 (In this case I would just say [arm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arm))

Comment: Thanks for the follow on q. The last question consensus is to not make a change

Answer (score 1):

The PPC and Intel and Apple Silicon tags all feel meta to me. Without clear guidance, they may struggle to stand alone and have limited usefulness for anyone to find questions. Let’s flesh out what each tag will be before we decide to make synonyms would be my advice. Precisely what questions belong to a tag and why not use other tags will help come to a consensus. Once we merge, it’s hard to fix, so I’d rather we have a couple extra tags for a few months than prematurely decide what to do here.

(And yes, [I was a bit short with Jeff Atwood](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/500/5472) about a somewhat analogous niche tag request before I had a few years experience here using tags, so I get the slight print of me arguing against “meta” or rare tags.)

If we had some great example of which questions this helps and how they can be used, it will make a decision more obvious. Specifically, we don’t really need tags for each iOS processor family since people have problems with phones and only occasionally with a specific iOS release.

Comment: We do need tags to denote architectures - for example questions about virtual machines will have different answers for intel, ppc and apple silicon/arm

Comment: The problem at the moment is that the choice of apple silicon or m1 is random - there is no differenciation

Comment: That’s a great start to editing the tag wikis to explain when the tag is to be used and relevant @mmmmmm

Comment: OK an edit to apple-silicon wiki (although the tag might be better as macOS-apple-silicon as Wikipedia includes iPhone chips in it) See the recent hot answers for good example of where this tag is needed.